# Where to propose a joint PhD program

Tags: phd, funding, europe

I am a mathematician, doing most of my research in dynamical systems. I would like to propose to an European academic partner to co-fund (50%-50%) a PhD position.
Is there a place on the web where I can describe my research interests and propose such kind of a joint PhD program?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "_co-found (50%-50%) a PhD position._".

Comment: With my research fund I am able to cover half of the cost of a PhD position, I'm searching someone pursuing similar research goals and interested in contribute to a PhD position with the missing half of the money.

Comment: @Nobody I'm sorry, I don't understand. I mean 1/2+1/2=1 PhD position (joint supervision).

Comment: So, you are a supervisor and looking for a co-supervisor? You actually mean "co-fund"? Please clarify.

Comment: Sure, co-found -> co-fund, corrected.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this via some website? To me co-supervision of a PhD student sounds like an substantial investment and I would prefer to have someone I know and trust for such an endeavour.

Comment: @Christian You are perfectly right. My problem is that I changed my main research field recently, so the personal relationships I built in some 15 years of previous activity are not so useful for my current purposes.

Comment: In general, I feel that such a web tool, if built cleverly enough, would increase the occasions of fruitful interaction. But maybe it simply doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm thinking that the rate of successful outcomes for the student of the near-random pairings of advisors coming out of even a 'clever' web tool would be pretty abysmal...